# Change Background Body Color If Seconds = 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, clock

I'm currently just trying to make a fun little clock and it's all working and everything. I would like the clock background color which is the body of the html to change color if seconds equals zero and then for it to change back to the color it was just on a second ago. The problem is I have made it so the user can change the background color of the clock so I can't just make it change back to a certain color, it needs to change back to the users color. I've tried storing it in variables and other things using javascript but I just have no idea how to do it. I've looked on the internet and can't seem to find anything that works!

Comment: so store the color in a variable and than set it back...

Answer (score 0):

You could store value of user background in another variable.

Since you didn't provide any code i can only guess that user picks color by clicking / typing into input field or some similar method.

In any case you can run "onchange", "onclick" or some other JS events. Use those events to get and store value into variable. And later on you can use value stored to restore color.

Examples: [w3schools - JS events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp)

Comment: [Please don't use w3schools as external ressource!](http://www.w3fools.com/) Prefer something like [MDN](http://mdn.io/events) instead!